# Negative Lookahead RegEx at Class Level RequestMapping

Tags: regex, spring, rest, controller, regex-lookarounds

I'm using Spring 3.0.1 and developing some REST calls. I have a regular expression I used earlier at the method level and it worked fine. However, due to changes in design I decided to separate all such calls into a separate controller. So, I configured the RequestMapping at the class level with the same RegEx but it does not seem to work. Is there a limitation to the type of RegEx that can be matched at the class level mappings? Below are the 2 calls:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/abcd")
public class ControllerClass 
{....
  @RequestMapping(value="/{var1}/{var2:(?!(ABC|XYZ).+/{var3}")
  public @ResponseBody SomeObject doSomething(@PathVariable("var1") String var1, @PathVariable("var2") String var2), @PathVariable("var3") String var3 {.....}
}
```

The above works fine and matches anything e.g. /abcd/random/HJGK/  and does not match /abcd/random/ABC/  as expected.

The below does not work in the same fashion  though:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/abcd/{var1}/{var2:(?!(ABC|XYZ).+}/")
public class ControllerClass 
{....
  @RequestMapping(value="{var3}/")
  public @ResponseBody SomeObject doSomething(@PathVariable("var1") String var1, @PathVariable("var2") String var2, @PathVariable("var3") String var3) {.....}
}
```

Any idea what might be different or wrong here?

Comment: I do not believe the former works as you have an issue there. Try `/abcd/{var1}/{var2:(?:(?!(?:ABC|XYZ)).)+}/`.

Comment: Hi stribzhev, your solution seems to exclude any version of ABC i.e. even if the string is HHDABC it'll still get excluded. I'm looking for only ABC or XYZ exactly to be excluded. Thanks for the assistance :)

Comment: Ok, then still you need to fix it as `@RequestMapping("/abcd/{var1}/{var2:(?!(ABC|XYZ)}).+}/")`. Does it work now?

Comment: Nope. For some reason it does not seem to pick it up. I keep getting the error of no mapping found for this HTTP request in DispatcherServlet.